# Extracting percentage with VLOOKUP to use in another table

Tags: excel, vlookup, percentage, extract

So I've got these 3 tables. The top one should be filled based on the other 2. Info in the grey cells is manually entered.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r3TW.jpg)

I've used VLOOKUP to get the Brand, Model and Year made and I need to calculate the Tax depending on the year the car has been made. Tax is product of Price and % for tax. The % for Tax should be extracted by the additional table. VLOOKUP should be used, range G17:H19 and the third argument being TRUE/FALSE.

Do I have to use a VLOOKUP inside VLOOKUP, because I've tried a few things and I keep getting #Value!, #N/A! or #Ref! errors.

*CLARIFICATION*: I have to extract the year it has been made from a table and then compare that to the additional table and check whether it's below 2013 or >=2013 and then use the corresponding percentage. I've manually added and highlighted the desired values.

Also is there a way to format a whole row based on the value in cell E9, meaning the row that contains that value gets formatted in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one VLOOKUP for this because the price of each car has already been entered. You just need to multiply it by the tax rate:

```
=B2*VLOOKUP(A2,G$11:H$13,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Notice that this formula returns errors for a couple of rows because there is no tax percentage for them.

If you want to use a default value when there isn't a year-specific value, let's say 13.2%, then your formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(B2*VLOOKUP(A2,G$11:H$13,2,FALSE),B2*0.132)
```

Comment: I think I mislead you. Somehow I need to extract the year made and then compare it to the additional table and check whether it's below 2013 or >=2013 and use the corresponding percentage.

Comment: Can you edit your initial screenshot and manually add the desired values you're looking for? Maybe highlight them as well so we'll know what the goal is. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm confused. Those are the exact values that my second formula above returns. If the year isn't listed in the table, then it multiples the rate by 13.2%, thus arriving at the exact same numbers you in your screenshot.

Comment: I think it's because you're using a shortened version of the table and your lookup_value is in the first column and what I've read for VLOOKUP is that it doesn't work if the lookup_value is not there, which in my case isn't. Thus it always gives an error and multiplies everything by 0.132 and gives wrong values.

Comment: That is incorrect. If you look at the picture I posted, it's only giving an error on two values (one which is covered up by the formula, and one which is visible). Those two values, predictably, are the ones for years 2005 and 2015, because they aren't in the table. The second formula I posted would multiply those two records by 13.2%. It would also multiply the 2012 record by 13.2% because that's the result from the table.

Comment: [My result](https://i.imgur.com/oXVoMRk.jpg). Am I doing something wrong, it multiplies everything by 13.2%?

Comment: Yes. Change the 5 to a 2.

Comment: [Picture..](https://i.imgur.com/WawXEcL.jpg) I still get wrong result for one of the cars and I honestly have no idea why.

Comment: Which car are you getting the wrong result for? And what result do you expect?

Comment: It's in the picture, the BMW one. I'm getting 7920 and I'm supposed to get 6240.

Comment: The BMW is a 2015. 2015 is not listed in your table of tax rates. If you'd like it to use a tax rate other than the 13.2%, then you should add it to your table.

Comment: I see your clarification above now. It looks like you want one value if it's before 2013 and another if it's after 2013. This is a completely different formula and doesn't even need a VLOOKUP. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per your clarification above, you don't need VLOOKUP for this since there are just two scenarios. You want it to return 13.2% if car is 2013 or newer, and 10.4% if car is 2012 or older.

Put the following formula in E5 and copy it down:

```
=IF(VALUE(D5)<2013,E5*.104,E5*.132)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and although that's the logic I have to follow, I'm required to use VLOOKUP for the task, which is confusing me.